# Duda sobre mi código

Tags: java

```
 public void setNombre_videojuego(String nombre_videojuego) {
 try{
  System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del videojuego: ");
  nombre_videojuego = lector.next();
  lector.nextLine();
 }
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("Error, no se ha introducido un nombre");
}

}
```

Está bien planteado mi metodo set para que el nombre del videojuego que yo meta no puede ser nulo ni vacío? 
En caso de que sea nulo me lanzará IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto te irá bien

```
    String nombre_videojuego = ""; 
    boolean lleno = false;
    do{
      System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del videojuego: ");
      nombre_videojuego = lector.nextLine();
      if(!nombre_videojuego.equals("")){
          lleno = true;
      }else{
          System.out.println("Error, no se ha introducido un nombre");
      }
    }while(!lleno);
```

Este código lo que hará es que mientras el String sea igual a "", entonces seguirá dentro del while. Si es diferente a "", entonces saldrá del while.

Answer (score 0):

1. Al salir del método, pierdes para siempre el valor introducido.

   a. No tiene sentido que recibas el nombre como parámetro si lo vas a leer de `lector`.
2. El nombre parece indicar que es un método *setter*. Los métodos *setter* típicamente cambian el valor de un atributo interno de la clase, pero el valor se les pasa por parámetro y no lo leen directamente de otro origen.

   a. Al incluir el código de lectura del setter a través del UI, impides que sea independiente de dicho UI.
3. Es imposible evaluar más sin saber de qué clase es `lector` una instancia. En caso de que, como parece, sea un `java.util.Scanner`, ni `next` ni `nextLine` documentan que lancen un `IllegalArgumentException`.

   a. Y aunque la lanzaran, el `catch`  capturaría dicha excepción.

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres admitir títulos sin contenidos tienes que comprobar que la String tiene al menos un elemento, puesto que el Scanner lea una cadena vacía no implica que esta sea defectuosa (Realmente lee el carácter de fin de línea).
Podrías comprobar que hay al menos un carácter con la función .lenght() de la clase string, y si no fuera así, volver a solicitar el dato o mostrar un mensaje de error, que lo puedes hacer con System.err.println().